# Functions are specific kind of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am just interested in really pining down the idea of functions. Given two sets X and Y together with function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ connecting X and Y. Is a function just the set that is realized through axiom of specification, i.e are we just looking at the following set ?

$$\{y \in Y : P(x,y) \ is \ true \ for \ x \in X \}$$

[image]

Comment: No: that set is the range of the function. The usual set-theoretic definition is that the function is the set $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times Y:P(x,y)\text{ is true}\}$; this author appears to want to define a function as a kind of machine described solely by its properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two ways to look at functions, as either mappings from $X$ to $Y$ as a relation $\ R \subset X \times Y$ that satisfies the constraint that if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(x,y') \in R$ then $y=y'$. If you graph a few functions you can convince yourself this is just the vertical line test as suggested in the article. I recommend small, finite sets to see what's happening. You can also draw a directed graph with vertices given by the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ with an edge given by $(x,y)$ to see how the mapping explicitly with arrows to reconcile the two notions of a function.